# Chrome popup window not working (works in IE)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have following code for a popup window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    popup = window.open("", "Chat", "scrollbars=no ,resizable=yes");
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = popup.document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = popup.document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    popup.document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

function login_to_chat() {
    var path = "/resources/livehelperchat/lhc_web/index.php/site_admin/chat/chattabs/";
    var params = {
        'lhc_user': '<?=$_SESSION['
        lhc_user '];?>',
        'lhc_password': '<?=$_SESSION['
        lhc_password '];?>'
    };
    post_to_url(path, params, "POST");
}
</script>
```

I have a link to open this popup window and call login_to_Chat():

```
<a href="javascript:login_to_chat();" title="">Support Chat</a>
```

IN IE it works fine - window shows up and the page to which I post loads correctly. 
It does not work in Chrome - popup window shows up, but nothing gets loaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does your console say, and does chrome show you a little notice that tells you it blocked a popup?

Comment: The URL is correct (works in IE) and no message from Chrome. Nothing in the console.

Comment: and what is that URL, so that we can verify that claim? =) (creating a jsfiddle.net instance is usually a good idea for questions like this. It lets us change the code, post an update, and go "this fixes it for you")